# Access dashDB (or DB2) using ibmdbPy from Python notebook

Tags: python, dashdb

I have been trying to access dashDB using ibmdbpy from Python. But it always crash when running script by following the guide. Could anyone have solution for this?

http://support.datascientistworkbench.com/knowledgebase/articles/860571-access-dashdb-or-db2-using-ibmdbpy-from-python-n

Below is the information for this article.

> IBM dashDB is a fully managed cloud data warehouse, purpose-built for analytics. In this article we will explore how to connect to it from a Python notebook and perform data access using ibmdbPy.
>
> The ibmdbpy library provides a Python interface for data manipulation and access to in-database algorithms in IBM dashDB and IBM DB2. It accelerates Python analytics by seamlessly pushing operations written in Python into the underlying database for execution, thereby benefiting from in-database performance-enhancing features, such as columnar storage and parallel processing.
>
> To get started you will need credentials for a dashDB database. If you don't already have an instance of dashDB you can get one for free by following steps in this article.
>
> The steps outlined below are included in a tutorial notebook  available on the Jupyter notebook Welcome screen of your Workbench.
>
> Lets start by loading ibmdbPy. We will also need to import JayDeBeAPI package to connect to the database using JDBC from ibmdbPy.

Comment: import jaydebeapi
from ibmdbpy import IdaDataBase
from ibmdbpy import IdaDataFrame

dsn_database = "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = ""
dsn_port = "50000"
dsn_uid = ""
dsn_pwd = ""


connection_string='jdbc:db2://'+dsn_hostname+':'+dsn_port+'/'+dsn_database+':user='+dsn_uid+';password='+dsn_pwd+";"
idadb=IdaDataBase(dsn=connection_string)

df=idadb.show_tables(show_all = True)
df.head(5)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and [edit] the question instead of adding the comments.